# Navigation topAppBar with BottomNavigation

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have problem with showing back button in topAppBar.
I have bottomNavigation for Home and favorite bikes.
When i want to show details of the bike I want back arrow to go back.

BottomNavGraph:

```
NavHost(
    navController =navController,
    startDestination = Screen.Home.route
){
    composable(route = Screen.Home.route){
        HomeScreen(navController = navController)
    }
    composable(route = Screen.Favorite.route){
        FavoriteScreen(navController = navController)
    }
    composable(route = Screen.Details.route){
        val bike = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.get<Bike>("bike")

        bike?.let{
            BikeDetaliScreen(navController = navController, movie)
        }

    }
```

And TopAppBar:

```
if(navController.previousBackStackEntry != null){
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painterResource(
                            id = R.drawable.bike_logo
                        ),
                        "Logo picture",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(130.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            },
            backgroundColor = Color(0xFF0B253F)
        )
    }
```

Problem is I want to have back arrow only in details screen, not in home or favorite. But when I use previousBackStackEntry != null somethimes favorite screen has arrow because it has homeScreen in stack.

Comment: I did not understand from your question what the problem is with your code. Please update the question with what behavior you expect and what you actually got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the current back stack entry and show/hide the back button accordingly.

```
// When you navigate to another screen, this value is updated.
val currentRoute = navController
    .currentBackStackEntryFlow
    .collectAsState(initial = navController.currentBackStackEntry)

val showBackButton = when (currentRoute.value?.destination?.route) {
    Screen.Home.route -> false
    else -> true
}

TopAppBar(
    ...
    navigationIcon = {
        if (showBackButton) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { ... }
            ) { Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBack, "Back") }
        }
    }
)
```